# UIScrollView Infinite scrolling setContentOffset

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

How is it possible to implement infinite scrolling with UIScrollView when calling setContentOffset: on UIScrollView halts the scrolling? Every time i reach end of my offset, I call this to make go back to the beginning of my offset but calling this causes the scrolling to stop.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`setContentOffset:` on it's own won't stop the scrolling. I suspect what's stopping the scroll is something like reaching the end of the `contentSize`. Try resetting the offset before you get to the end of the content size.

How you do this depends on your implementation. For example, simply increasing contentSize by {50, 50} may solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Check the **StreetScroller** sample and the [Advanced Scroll View Techniques](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/advanced-scrollview-techniques.html#advanced-scrollview-techniques) from WWDC2011.

Comment: Great video, thanks for the link. If you have any follow-ups that show how to do infinite scrolling in both x and y I'd be extremely grateful :)